# SPI NOR Partitioning and read/write from u-boot C code

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

We have BBB based custom board,
we have SPI NOR flash and NAND flash on the board,
We were able to make mtd partitions for NAND. But NOR partitioning is not working :(
we added following defines to make mtd NOR partitions.

```
#define MTDIDS_DEFAULT "nand0=omap2-nand.0, nor0=omap2-nor.0"
#define MTDPARTS_DEFAULT "mtdparts=omap2-nand.0:" \
"128k(SPL)," \
"128k(SPL.backup1)," \
"128k(SPL.backup2)," \
"128k(SPL.backup3)," \
"1024k(u-boot)," \
"1024k(u-boot.backup1)," \
"128k(u-boot-env)," \
"5m(kernel)," \
"5m(kernel.backup1)," \
"512k(fdt)," \
"512k(fdt.backup1)," \
"100m(rootfs)," \
"100m(rootfs.backup1)," \
"13m(reserved)," \
";" \
"mtdparts=omap2-nor.0:" \
"128k(SPL1_nor)," \
"128k(SPL2_nor)," \
"128k(SPL3_nor)," \
"128k(SPL4_nor)," \
"512k(usr_nor)," \
```

Another doubt is,
Is it possible to do read/write using mtd device files in u-boot ?
As i understand it, u-boot also uses Linux's mtd drivers, so
Is it possible to do something like fd = open("/dev/mtd0",O_WRONLY) from u-boot code ?

Comment: "Is it possible to do something like fd = open("/dev/mtd0",O_WRONLY) from u-boot code ?" u-boot is not an OS it just a boot loader. You can not do that code in u-boot.

Comment: @sessyargc.jp thank your attention, I agree that it might not be possible for u-boot code, but i was also curious to know if it is possible or not. I was wondering if u-boot is using Linux mtd driver then won't it be possible to use it like Linux.

Comment: Indeed u-boot is using a stripped down version of the Linux mtd driver but the other requirements to use u-boot as such is not available to u-boot. For one, u-boot does not have a complete filesystem.

Comment: I agree with you on that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to allow partitioning the SPI NOR, I added the following at the end of spi_flash_probe():

```
/* Release spi bus */
spi_release_bus(spi);

extern nand_info_t nand_info[];
struct mtd_info *mtd;

mtd = &nand_info[1];
mtd->name = "nor0";
mtd->size = flash->size;
mtd->erasesize = flash->erase_size;
mtd->writesize = flash->page_size;
mtd->priv = flash;
mtd->_write = sf_mtdwrite;
mtd->_read = sf_mtdread;
mtd->_erase = sf_mtderase;
#ifdef CONFIG_MTD_DEVICE
add_mtd_device(mtd);
#endif

return flash;
```

However there is no concept of, e.g., "reading/writing/erasing a partition", these exist separately for NAND and SPIFLASH. So, defining a partition on the SPI NOR is not very useful, except if a generic mtd command (mtd write, mtd read, mtd erase...) is to be created.

Comment: Thank you for reply. At the moment we replaced whole SPI + NAND combination with eMMC so we wouldn't need these changes. From the changes it looks like mtd partitions would also work with these changes.